# should not allow space in textbox..Is it possible to use two onblur's in one textbox?

Tags: java, html

How can i avoid the space in my texbox..?
I tried with trim but it is not working.
I'm gonna enter integer value in textbox, it should not take white space while clicking next button

Comment: Where is the code related to it?

Comment: How come trim() is not working?. It would be better if you post your code. trim() will solve your problem

Comment: <Field:text name="text1" onblur="RiskUnitId()" labelID="MSG_GS_104300"/>

Comment: **JAVA** and **JavaScript** are two **Completely Different** things.

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as Car is to Carpet

Answer (score 0):

```
CString strTemp = "";
strTemp.Replace(" ","");
```

This replaces all the spaces present in your string assigned to the textbox..

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
<script>
        function RestrictSpace() {
         if (event.keyCode == 32) {
             event.returnValue = false;
             return false;
             }
            }
    </script>
<input name="Textboxname" id="TextBoxId" value="false" onkeypress="RestrictSpace()" type="text"/>
```

Comment: What is that event.keyCode == 32.?

Comment: @SandeepNayak I dont saw it before post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fix = function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/ /g, ''));
}

$(function () {
    $("#mytextbox").change(fix).keydown(fix);
});
```

At jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2BSzZ/

Answer (score -1):

```
function trim(s)
{    
    s.value = s.value.replace('/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/',''); 
    s.value = s.value.replace('/[ ]{2,}/gi','');     
    s.value = s.value.replace('/\n +/',"\n");           
    return;
}
```

text box not allow the multiple space between twowords